# Barcode scanning with ZX and front facing camera

Tags: android, zxing

I'm using the following code to fire an Intent to start the ZX barcode scanner. I've tweaked it to use the front-facing camera, but this appears to be failing to scan any barcodes because the front-facing image is reversed (I'm assuming this is the reason). ie a book barcode shows NBSI (with backwards letters) rather than ISBN. Using the rear facing camera a Nexus 5 and Nexus 7 can both scan barcodes. When switching to the front camera both fail to recognise barcodes.

How do I tweak my Intent so ZX shows a non-reversed front-facing camera image?

```
private void startBarcodeScanner() {
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(MainActivity.this);
    integrator.addExtra("SCAN_CAMERA_ID", getFrontCameraId());
    integrator.addExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
    integrator.initiateScan(IntentIntegrator.PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES);
}

private int getFrontCameraId() {
    int cameraId = -1;
    int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            cameraId = i;
            return cameraId;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Works Perfectly with Tab S7 with slight modification:

```
public void barcodeButtonPressed(View v){
    IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);       
    scanIntegrator.addExtra("SCAN_CAMERA_ID", getFrontCameraId());
    //scanIntegrator.addExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");

    scanIntegrator.initiateScan(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We did more testing on other devices and it DOES scan barcodes using the front facing camera using the code above. For some reason on my N5 and N7 it fails, but I'll have to put it down to focus/lighting.

I'll leave the question up in case anyone else wants to confirm ZX does scan barcodes using the front facing camera out of the box.